# My Domain change and SSO

Tags: mydomain, identity-provider

We are changing our My domain after company name change. We have a couple of SSO configured in our org, I know that endpoints will change automatically once new My domain is deployed but do I have to change the "Entity ID" in SAML Single Sign-On Settings to reflect the new domain?

Also, do I have to change something on the IdP side (Azure in this case)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know first hand knowledge about Azure sso but have built sso with okta  and others. We configure details in both system. When url changes in one system, that needs to be reflected in other system. Otherwise Azure will post saml response to wrong url and would error out.

For reference, here is sample sso config in sfdc which has entity id which would change in your case.

```xml
<SamlSsoConfig xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <identityLocation>SubjectNameId</identityLocation>
    <identityMapping>Username</identityMapping>
    <issuer>la20ufijlfsdljasflj</issuer>
    <loginUrl>https://apps.company1.com/app/salesforce/la20ufijlfsdljasflj/sso/saml</loginUrl>
    <logoutUrl>https://apps.company1.com</logoutUrl>
    <name>Okta</name>
    <oauthTokenEndpoint>https://company1.my.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token</oauthTokenEndpoint>
    <redirectBinding>false</redirectBinding>
    <requestSignatureMethod>1</requestSignatureMethod>
    <requestSigningCertId>0P1xxxxxxxxxxus</requestSigningCertId>
    <salesforceLoginUrl>https://company1.my.salesforce.com</salesforceLoginUrl>
    <samlEntityId>https://company1.my.salesforce.com</samlEntityId>
    <samlVersion>SAML2_0</samlVersion>
    <useConfigRequestMethod>true</useConfigRequestMethod>
    <userProvisioning>false</userProvisioning>
    <validationCert>...CertContent...</validationCert>
</SamlSsoConfig>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, very helpful indeed! The endpoint will obviously change and that needs to be changed in Azure, but how the Entity ID is used? Can it remain the same? Or is it mandatory to change to the new domain?

Comment: Entity id is saml concept which identifies either idp or sp. Typically that be the assertion consumer service or domain which receives the assertion. You could keep old value as is but that would just cause confusion for others.